# Django: Using named parameters on a raw SQL query

Tags: python, django, mariadb

I'm trying to execute a raw query that is built dynamically.
To assure that the parameters are inserted in the valid position I'm using named parameters.

This seems to work for Sqlite without any problems. (all my tests succeed)
But when I'm running the same code against MariaDB it fails...

A simple example query:

```
 SELECT u.* 
    FROM users_gigyauser AS u
  WHERE u.email like :u_email
    GROUP BY u.id
    ORDER BY u.last_login DESC
  LIMIT 60 OFFSET 0
```

Parameters are:

```
 {'u_email': '%test%'}
```

The error I get is a default syntax error as the parameter is not replaced.
I tried using '%' as an indicator, but this resulted in SQL trying to parse

```
%u[_email]
```

and that returned a type error.

I'm executing the query like this:

```py
raw_queryset = GigyaUser.objects.raw(
    self.sql_fetch, self._query_object['params']
)
```

Or when counting:

```py
cursor.execute(self.sql_count, self._query_object['params'])
```

Both give the same error on MariaDB but work on Sqlite (using the ':' indicator)

Now, what am I missing?

Comment: using %(u_email) as stated in the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/) results in a "incomplete format " error btw

Comment: the docs says `%(u_email)s` (notice the suffix `s`)

Comment: TNX!!!!!
If you put this comment as a answer, it can be marked as answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

edit:

The format needs to have `s` suffix as following:

```
%(u_email)s
```

Comment: There is a reason for not using the ORM,.. and it is a good one.
I'm not afraid for sql-injection... so that is not a problem either.

Comment: Django orm is nice for the simple object related database queries.
When however your database structure becomes more advanced and you need to generate exact reports/selections things go bad.
I need to generate specialized selections based on a dynamic json object.. generated by a javascript tool

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQLite3, for some reason syntax `%(name)s` will not work.
You have to use `:name` syntax instead if you want to pass your params as `{"name":"value"}` dictionary.

It's contrary to the documentation, that states the first syntax should work with all DB engines.

Heres the source of the issue:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10070#comment:18